# How to Display different Custom arabic fonts in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, arabic, uifont, custom-font

In my application i need to display arabic text with different custom fonts. I follow the scenario adding `ttf` files to `info.plist`.

As per above scenario i am successfully getting display text in different font style for **ENGLISH** text only. I am doing same thing for **arabic** font styles but here i am not getting. Why is going like that?

Please any one can help me

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How do you load and set the font ?. I had this issue with Hebrew fonts but I could fix it

Comment: I just add ttf files to the resource folder and add those name in UIAppFonts in info.plist   how did solve your problem. Please help me in this issue.

Comment: @KAREEMMAHAMMED : Did you find solution for Arabic fonts?

Comment: Yes by adding ttf files to application info.plist we can use them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Kareem , I took hint from Stackoverflow itself to load the fonts but could not get it working in first go. May be following steps can help you .

1. Add the font files to your project.
2. Make their entries in info.plist file

   such as [image]
3. you can now implement some method that loads your font somewhere in
   application delegate 
        like

   -(UIFont*) CustomFontWithSize:(float)size{

   ```
       UIFont* customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FX_Masa" size:size];

       if(customFont == nil)
           customFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:size];

       return customFont;
   }
   ```

If you notice then the name I have passes here is "FX_MASA" and not FX_MasaRegular , this was the point where I was wrong. The name that we need to use while fetching the font is the INSTALL NAME (Double click on the font to install the font on system and the name that appears in Font Book is the install name).

[image]

Hope this helps your problem as well. In case you come across any good method, please update here.

Comment: Though I am still using it on device, If you come across any update , please do share with all of us. Thanks

Comment: Also This was only a workaround that I could find. I now have a systematic approach that I use to add custom fonts in my application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice UILabel extension in GitHub called "Font Label": https://github.com/zynga/FontLabel
This allows to load any TTF file and then draw ZLabel objects (ZLabel is an extension of UILabel) with this custom font. It is based on CoreGraphics and I tested with many custom fonts and proved to work correctly. I don't know of course the effect with arabic fonts, but it's worth a try and a feedback from you (to us and also the github project admins) is welcome.

Comment: Hi thanks for response  I tried above example it also doesn't give custom fonts for arabic. Is there any way for especially arabic like UNICODE etc... Please help in this    issue Thanks for advance