# How to set Arabic text to right and English text to left on same label

Tags: objective-c, layout, ios6, arabic, right-to-left

I learned how to make English and Arabic project from [previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301523/language-switcher-in-ios6).

### [Same Project at github](https://github.com/j4n0/14301523)

Now what I did is added a label in this project and wrote **"Welcome"**.

***The problem is the layout.*** When I have English text it is at left side (obviously), but when the Arabic text comes, it should start from right to left. But it is aligned to left only.

Any idea how to deal with such case?

Below are the screenshots...

### English

[image]

### Arabic

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is what I did...

Added fonts in projects folder (english.ttf & arabic.ttf) as shown [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223538/how-to-display-different-custom-arabic-fonts-in-iphone-application).

In `Localizable.strings` added `"myFont"="ACS  Zomorrod";` (Arabic) & `"myFont"="Armalite Rifle";` (English)

and then had those font in condition

```
NSString *myFont = localize(@"myFont");
NSString *cpFont = @"Armalite Rifle";
if ([myFont isEqualToString:cpFont]) {
    self.myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft; // this is for English
} else {
    self.myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight; // this is for Arabic
}
```

---

### Edit 1

Also you could have `"myLang"="arabic";` & `"myLang"="english";` in `Localizable.strings` and then have code as

```
NSString *myLang = localize(@"myFont");
NSString *myActualLang = @"english";
if ([myLang isEqualToString:myActualLang]) {
    self.myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft; // this is for English
} else {
    self.myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight; // this is for Arabic
}
```

**I will prefer the second option instead of first as tomorrow if I change the font, I would have to do changes at line `NSString *cpFont = @"Armalite Rifle";` in all files.**

Answer (score 1):

**Conditional if-else**

Check for your font and change the alignment.

Or,

Make two labels for each of them setting their alignemnt Left-Right and Right-Left and show the text on either by checking the language.

Comment: Who will show the string in your textbox? You only will be passing text and font type to show it, am I wrong?

Comment: I don't have any textbox... i have label and button... how to deal in this case?

Comment: and how can i set two font for same textbox??

Comment: same thing if(fontName==ArbicOrSomehing){...} else{...}

Comment: check my answer. Is that you was trying to say??

Comment: that worked, but don't know why I didn't get what you said. I feel if you would have said, write font name in `Localizable.strings` and then use `if.. else`, i would have gotten your point. Still thanks for help...

Comment: Now, if you read my answer again, you will get exactly what i asked to  do. Might be my communication wasn't good. :(

Comment: may be communication was point. :) I will upvote as u gave me HINT :)

Comment: but I am facing problem with Arabic font... see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337547/why-arabic-font-is-not-showing-in-iphone-i-can-see-text-but-not-font)