# Why arabic font is not showing in iPhone (I can see text, but not font)

Tags: objective-c, fonts, ios6, arabic

I am writing arabic text programmatically as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8226107/1066828) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14337144/1066828).

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14337144/1066828) solution, I can see english text in proper font, however when I am doing same with Arabic font, default font is coming and not the real one. Below are the screenshots for the same.

### English working fine

[image]

### Arabic taking default font instead of actual font

[image]

### Font.ttf screenshot

[image]

Downloaded arabic font from [here](http://freearabicfonts.com/Free_Arabic_Fonts?s8). (third font in list Font #: 23)...

***My Question Is***, why this is happening with Arabic font?

---

***I checked with Hindi font and it is working fine. The only problem is with ARABIC font.***

Comment: You need to install that font on your system and also on iphone.

Comment: I feel, FONT is getting applied and that is why I can see larger text, not the smaller default one. BUT why font is not working then?

Comment: I have installed font on mac and iPhone too. still same problem... 3rd screenshot is from my mac only

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441238/arabic-text-with-custom-fonts-in-ios

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri : Second answer of your solution is not working.

Comment: @FahimParkar : As i googled an in SO, there are a lot of similar questions. I am sure you must have seen them. And few days back... I suggested someone to **Re install the font** and it worked.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya : re-install not working...

Comment: ok, what if you change the localization settings?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya : why to change localization setting? I don't have two InfoPlist.strings